# Installed new alternator, now no power

Tags: alternator

I just put a new alternator on my 76 Winnebago motor home yesterday and it started just fine two times and now I have no power at all. No head lights, no cigarette lighter, nothing.

Tested the batteries and they read 12 V with motor off. I can't check when running because there's no power. So what could be causing my motor to have no power now?

Comment: Does the Winnebago have a Chevrolet engine in it? And if so, what size/kind? First think I'd look at is to ensure you hooked the battery up, then ensure all of your power leads from there are correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Test the battery at the terminals
2. Test the positive on the battery with the ground to the frame
3. Double-check that the alternator is hooked up correctly
4. Is there power to one system but not another? Check your fuses.

If you aren't getting power to *anything* start at the source (battery) and work your way in. Follow the wires. Check your grounds. Don't forget to check any fusible links, they look like wires but are actually fuses. (old car thing) You can squeeze them and look for a "hollow" spot.

Answer (score 0):

If the battery has 12v power supply and still if some electrical circuits are not working, then please check the fuses of relevant circuits, probably there is a common fuse that might have blown. If you are able to start the car that means the battery charge is fine. If you are able to start the engine, then check the voltage at battery at idling. The voltage at battery with engine running will be more than 13V which means the alternator is charging the battery

Answer (score 0):

check the fuse box and you should check your charging voltage first when the car is running check the voltage on the battery it should be around 13 v if its more then the regulator on the alternator is faulty and is over charging and that might be the reason you fuses blew out. if the alternator is reading more than 13 v don't keep it running as it can damage you batter and other electrics